# Converted site from claims back to Windows auth - accesss denied

Tags: claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

We attempted to convert a web app that was set up in claims back to NTLM/Windows auth.

First we unchecked the claims provider in the web app properties in CA. We realized we were still getting claims accounts registered in the user list with the claims account prefix "i:O#.w".

We then ran the following script on the web app:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mywebapp"
$webApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = 0;
$webApp.Update()
```

This did change the web app setting to Classic. We then found we no longer had access to the site with any account.

We tried manually changing SC admins in CA to the Windows accounts. The changes were accepted, however access was still denied.

We also manually converted some accounts with the following script. Access was still denied after this.

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin "i:0#.w|domain\userid" -newlogin domain\userid -ignoresidhistory
```

What did we miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know converting from Claims to classic isn't supported.

I'd delete the old web application, BUT keep the content database.
Create a new web app using the old content database.
Assign new windows site collection admin and the re-create all permissions using windows accounts groups.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't really find out what was missing. We found a few web.config settings that when removed allowed the site to work. That however just made us more nervous about where we were heading with all this.

So to be safe, we detached the content databases, recreated the web application and site collections, then reattached the content databases. It didn't take all that long to complete either.

Answer (score 0):

Use Powershell:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mywebapp"
$webApp.MigrateUsers($true)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried this, but it didn't work.